# how to show fetched data using axios to div in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

i am very new to vue, i am trying to fetch blog from codeigniter backend using axios api. but i am not able to understand how to populate that in div.

i use v-if and it generate 6 lists but data is not there also how to work with background image here.

in json response there is thumbnail : "https://url.com/uploads/thumb213.jpg". how to show that using v-bind.

```
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#blogapp',
        data () {
            return {
               blogs: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getBlogs () {
            axios
            .get('https://www.happyvoyaging.com/api/blog/list?appkey="grv250531"')
            .then(response => (this.blogs = response))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        },
        },

        mounted() {
           this.getBlogs();
         },
        })
</script>
```

this is the component part

```
         <div v-for="blog in blogs" class="col-md-3">
        <div">
          <a href="blog-post.html"></a>
          <div class="banner">
            <div class="banner-bg" v-bind:style="background-image:url('{{ blog.thumbnail }}');"></div>
            <div class="banner-caption">
              <p class="theme-blog-item-time">day ago</p>
              <h5 class="title">{{ blog.title }}</h5>
              <p class="desc">{{ blog.desc }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

this is the response in json

```
    error: {status: false, msg: ""}
response: {posts: [{id: "44", title: "Andaman Islands: The Complete Guide for Travellers",…},…], totalPages: 2}
posts: [{id: "44", title: "Andaman Islands: The Complete Guide for Travellers",…},…]
0: {id: "44", title: "Andaman Islands: The Complete Guide for Travellers",…}
1: {id: "43", title: "Russia Visa for Indians",…}
2: {id: "42", title: "Dubai Creek – Sail through the heart of Dubai",…}
3: {id: "41", title: "A Must Follow Guide To Japan Visa Requirements",…}
4: {id: "40", title: "Russia to resume issuing visas to all categories of Indian citizens",…}
5: {id: "23", title: "Trapizzino, Rome’s OG Street Food",…}
6: {id: "17", title: "Where to Eat in Rome During Holidays",…}
totalPages: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting to the data

The `axios.get()` callback stores the response in the [`data` property](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema), but your API data itself contains the blog data inside `response.posts`, so the property path to that is `res.data.response.posts`:

```js
axios.get(/*...*/).then(res => this.blogs = res.data.response.posts)
```

### Binding style

The binding value for `v-bind:style` should be a string or a JavaScript expression for a string (such as [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or string concatenation):

```html
<div class="banner-bg" v-bind:style="background-image:url('{{ blog.thumbnail }}');"></div> ❌

<div class="banner-bg" v-bind:style="`background-image:url('${blog.thumbnail}');`"></div> ✅
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/VwPJymx?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem is with your getBlog function's then block. You are doing this.blogs=response. you can get the data from the response by doing response.data.posts
Simply replace your:

```
methods: {
        getBlogs () {
        axios
        .get('https://www.happyvoyaging.com/api/blog/list?appkey="grv250531"')
        .then(response => (this.blogs = response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    },
```

part with below code:

```
methods: {
        getBlogs () {
        axios
        .get('https://www.happyvoyaging.com/api/blog/list?appkey="grv250531"')
        .then(response => (this.blogs = response.data.posts))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    },
    },
```

It should work like this