# Getting data with Axios from .json in a vue loop

Tags: json, vue.js, axios, tailwind-ui

In my Navigation I want to insert Links from my CMS. I am using Axios. My Navigation is Vue. How do I get the data from the JSON file into the const?

Just knowing if I need to search for the solution in Axios or in Vue would help alot too.

```
import axios from "axios";

const exhibitions = [
    {
    name: "Exhibition 1",
    description: "Info 1",
    href: "#",
    },

    {
    name: "Exhibition 2",
    description: "Info 2",
    href: "#",
    },    
];
```

my export default:

```
export default {
  name: "item",
  data() {
    return {
      info: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/posts.json")
      .then((response) => (this.info = response));
  },
```

posts.json

```
{
"data":
    [{
    "id":1028,
    "title":"Exhibition 1",
    "slug":"exhibition-2009",
    "url":"http://localhost:8000/exhibitions/exhibition-2009"
    },
    {
    "id":905,
    "title":"Exhibition 2",
    "slug":"exhibition-2006",
    "url":"http://localhost:8000/exhibitions/exhibition-2006"
    }],
"meta":
    {
    "pagination":
    {
    "total":2,
    "count":2,
    "per_page":100,
    "current_page":1,
    "total_pages":1,
    "links":{}
     }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show fetched data using axios to div in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342628/how-to-show-fetched-data-using-axios-to-div-in-vuejs)

Comment: The json file shows in the Developer Tools Console. But from there I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do you mean by "Get the data from the JSON into the **const**"??

> Just a reminder, a constant cannot be modified.

According to what you commented, I guess that you'd like to store the data fetched from your json file to `info` **variable**. And then, render your links in the navigation bar.

```
mounted() {
    axios
       .get("http://localhost:8000/posts.json")
       .then((response) => (this.info = response));
}
```

Once the component is mounted you're fetching your JSON data from the file using Axios. When the promise is accepted then you store the response data to `this.info`. Once you have your data in that variable you can render everything ⬇️

There's a directive in VueJS for list rendering called **v-for**. You can use it to render all the links to your navigation bar.

```
<ul id="navigation-bar">
    <li v-for="i in info">
        <a href="{{ i.url }}"> {{ i.title }} </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please better explain your solution [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks the info about the constant. I do understand and will try it.

Comment: Actually, what's what you want to achieve? 

Comment: @jiahui-chen I would like to load 2 infos (Title and URL) from a .json file (exported from CraftCMS) into my vue.js Navigation.

Comment: @jiahui-che Or can I describe it better like this: I want the links from my CMS to appear in the Vue navigation.

Comment: @Oli I've updated my response, I hope it helps and does what you want

Comment: @jiahui-che Thank you. Yes I did this, getting back empty list items. If I give out only:  {{ i }} I receive the full json. I tried many times, always this result. May be the mistake is in my json file? I will add it to my question.

Comment: Can you please format the JSON correctly? I mean, with all the curly braces and commas. It took me some time to decode the actual JSON. But I think you should do `info.data` in the **v-for="i in info.data"**

Comment: @jiahui-chen  I formatted the JSON. 
v-for="i in info.data" does not give the title, url back either. Can I try something else?

Comment: @Oli `v-for="i in info.data.data"` should render everything. But I'd recommend you to assign **this.info = response.data.data** and then render the list as I've told you in the response

Comment: @jiahui-chen Yes. Now I got it. Thank you. It is showing the titles as you told.

Comment: Glad that it finally worked! Could you please up vote, the response  it should help future readers. Thank you @Oli